# Get password in account user in AppDynamics

Tags: appdynamics, app-dynamics-query-language

I'm working in an instance of AppDynamics where we enter using SSO, so we just type the name of our account and enter without an user/password.

I need to create a custom event and, according to this documentation `https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Alert+and+Respond+API#AlertandRespondAPI-CreateaCustomEvent`

what I would need is to run a curl like `curl -X POST --user user1@customer1:secret 'http://demo.appdynamics.com/controller/rest/applications/5/events?severity=INFO&summary=test1&eventtype=CUSTOM&customeventtype=mycustomevent&propertynames=key1&propertynames=key2&propertyvalues=value1&propertyvalues=value'`

Problem is, I don't have an user/password. If I don't type them I get a 401 as expected.

I can see in `My Preferences` my username, but I can't find any password in the application.

Is there something I could do to find that password or something that would work for that POST to work?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials for an SSO user reside with the Identity Provider (on your side) not the Service Provider (AppDynamics).

So there are two options here:

1. Create (or ask an admin to create) an AppDynamics user in the Controller Administration UI. Then use the username / password from this user in your requests.
2. Create (or ask an admin to create) and API Client configuration in the Controller Administration UI. Then use the Access Token in your requests (Docs: https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/22.x/latest/en/extend-appdynamics/appdynamics-apis/api-clients)